# How to iterate more pythonic for a case?

Tags: python

Here is the case:
`mylist = range(100)` and I have a discontinuous path from `src=1` to `dest=99` with an array `pre[100]`, each value of which represents the last `elem` in the `path`.
The question is: How can I get all the `elems` in the `path` from `dest` to `src`. Can do like this:

```
    path = []
    i = dst
    while i != src:
      path.append(i)
      i = pre[i]
    path.append(src)
```

But, is there any simpler way maybe using just only one statement?

**Sample Input**

```
dst, src = 3, 2
pre = [2, 0, 3, 1]
```

**Output**

```
[3, 1, 0, 2]   #It just have to follow the path with the indices from 3 to 2.
```

Explanation:

```
              src  dst
                v  v
Indices:  0  1  2  3
Pre    :  2  0  3  1

From dest 3, the predecessor is 1, so we go to 1.
From node 1, the predecessor is 0, so we go to 0.
From node 0, the predecessor is 2, so we go to 2.
2 is src, so we're done.
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of inputs and output?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What is `pre` exactly? Show some code people can run and see exactly what you want. Otherwise it's pretty cryptic.

Comment: None of the comprehension techniques or the lambda allows assignment. So, I don't believe an oneliner is possible for this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `pre` is a predecessor in a directed graph. So I think this is part of a backtracking from found destination, to get a list from `src` to `dest`

Comment: People, please dont close this question. This is an interesting one I really would like to see a solution. Lets let the gurus answer this.

Comment: one-liner == pythonic now?

Answer (score 4):

The Pythonic way is to either use your existing loop, or to use an equivalent generator function:

```
def gen_path(src, dst, pre):
    while dst != src:
        yield dst
        dst = pre[dst]
    yield src
```

Then to get a list, you'd call it with `list(gen_path(src, dst, pre))`.

There is no way to do this in a single basic expression, because there is state involved (what node in the path you're on). It probably is possible using complicated, hackish stuff like 2-argument `next` and `lambda`s with default arguments, but you don't want to go there.

Comment: _Definitely_ possible with "lambdas with default arguments"

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE**: I am *not* recommending this.  In real code I would write the loop.  The loop is simple and clear.  The loop is already pythonic.  Maybe use `yield` instead of materializing a list, but that's easy.

As I put it once: "What seems unpythonic to me is spending time worrying about making perfectly clear code more pythonic. The Pythonicness which needs hours of thought is not the true Pythonicness."

---

But for entertainment purposes, and because the Colts just won, a one-liner:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile, accumulate, repeat
>>> dst, src = 3, 2
>>> pre = [2, 0, 3, 1]
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x: x != src, 
                   accumulate(repeat(dst), lambda x,y: pre[x]))) + [src]
[3, 1, 0, 2]
```

This will only work in Python >= 3.3, in which `accumulate` accepts a binary-argument function as its second argument.  This comes in useful in cases where you want a `reduce` which gives the partial results, and reminding everyone about this new functionality is about the only excuse I have for this answer..

Answer (score 2):

Not to be outonelined by @DSM

```
z = lambda i=dst, p=[]: p if p.append(i) or i==src else z(pre[i]); z()
```

Needless to say - noone should use code like this